# React component for size control of CSS variable

Tags: react.js, typescript

So I spend a day trying to understand how could I resize components, I came up with this method which surely isn't the best, but I liked it:

1. Create  component
2. This component uses mouse events to change a CSS variable for another component
3. It doesnt use much of the react syntax or stuff, as I am a beginner

What I would like is if someone gives some feed back as to what improvements are more important to write in a more "react-like" way

This is the [working demo](https://codepen.io/mahneh/pen/rNQLwWx)

And the plain component code:

```js
import { MouseEvent } from 'react';

const supportedEvents = ['mousemove', 'mouseout'] as const;

/**
 * This component allows user to manipulate a css size variable
 * The component should be located in a grid besides the element to resize,
 */
export function SplitVertical() {
  const root = document.documentElement;

  function handleMouseEvent(e: MouseEvent) {
    const mouseDownWidthValue = parseInt(
      getComputedStyle(root).getPropertyValue('--filesystem-width')
    );
    // this wrapper helps to have the right function reference
    // so that the event listeners can be removed.
    function resizeXEvent(e: globalThis.MouseEvent) {
      return resizeX(e, oldValue, root);
    }

    const resizerElement = e.currentTarget as HTMLDivElement;
    // in this case, e.pageX is the initial position of the mouse (on mouse down)
    const positionOnDown = e.pageX;
    const oldValue = positionOnDown - mouseDownWidthValue;

    if (resizerElement !== null) {
      root.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
        supportedEvents.forEach((event) => {
          resizerElement.removeEventListener(event, resizeXEvent, true);
        });
      });
      if (e.type === 'mousedown') {
        supportedEvents.forEach((event) => {
          resizerElement.addEventListener(event, resizeXEvent, true);
        });
      }
    }
  }
  return <div className="resizer-x" onMouseDown={handleMouseEvent}></div>;
}

function resizeX(
  e: globalThis.MouseEvent,
  oldValue: number,
  root: HTMLElement
) {
  const positionOnMove = e.pageX;
  const extra = positionOnMove - oldValue;
  if (extra < 100 || extra > 700) return;
  root.style.setProperty('--filesystem-width', extra + 'px');
}
```